# Using 2PC in Entgo

Tags: go

In Entgo, assuming that the database is Postgres which supports 2 Phase Commit using the `PREPARE TRANSACTION` command, how can I create such transaction and then externally manage it (using an aggregation layer on top of microservices)? I can do this by directly interacting with the database driver but what I am asking in particular is that, is there a high level API in Entgo for this? (I didn't find anything the documentation)